# Changing ownership of Salesforce File

Tags: chatter-file, ownership

The organization I'm working in has a file that gets distributed quite a bit internally owned by a former employee. They are looking to change that ownership of the File (created in Chatter), and the only way I could figure out how was programmatically via APEX.

```
ContentDocument cd = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = '069G0000000fkoo'];
cd.OwnerId = '005G0000002co1Z';
update cd;
```

I'm curious if anyone else has any idea how to do it through the UI?

[It looks like you can change CRM Content owners](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm), but I can't find anything on Files. I took a look at [Salesforce's recommended usage of the different file storage types](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_differences.htm&language=en_US) and I am inferring they didn't structure Files in a way that you'd want to transfer ownership.

I also can't see a way to inject a custom VF page onto that page to allow users to transfer ownership on their own without developer/administrator help (although this is likely not going to be a frequent request).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is currently not possible to do via VF. You can add collaborators under the Shared WIth section of the record. It may still be possible to do via some 3rd party tools but at least there seems to be no official way of doing this. Read more [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&id=90630000000gjXqAAI)

Comment: I ended up having to do this via Anonymous Apex. Too bad nothing exists in the UI for Admins.